Kotlin Serialization: How to handle null values in a custom serializer
In my API, there are many JSON values that come as a JSON object with value, description, such as this:
{
    id: 1321,
    season: {
        value: *some value*,
        description: *some description*
    },
    ...,
    type: {
        value: *some value*,
        description: *some description*
    }
}

The value field is always some Enum, and description doesn't carry any informative value for me.
To get free of unnecessary nesting I tried to make a custom serializer, and it works fine:
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
open class EnumSerializer<T : Enum<T>>(
    private val serializer: KSerializer<T>
) : KSerializer<T> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor(serializer.descriptor.serialName) {
        element("value", serializer<String>().descriptor)
        element("description", serializer<String>().descriptor)
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: T) {
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(serializer, value)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): T {
        return decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            lateinit var value: String

            while (true) {
                when (val i = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                    CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break
                    0 -> value = decodeStringElement(descriptor, i)
                    1 -> decodeStringElement(descriptor, i)
                    else -> throw SerializationException("Unknown index $i")
                }
            }

            defaultJson.decodeFromString(serializer, value)
        }
    }
}

I then use it as follows:
internal object SeasonEnumSerializer : EnumSerializer<SeasonApi>(SeasonApi.generatedSerializer())

@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializable(with = SeasonEnumSerializer::class)
@KeepGeneratedSerializer
enum class SeasonApi(val value: String) {
    @SerialName("winter") WINTER("winter"),
    @SerialName("spring") SPRING("spring"),
    @SerialName("summer") SUMMER("summer"),
    @SerialName("autumn") AUTUMN("autumn");

    override fun toString(): String = value
}


@Serializable
data class ReleaseApi(
    @SerialName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerialName("season") val season: SeasonApi?,
    ...
    @SerialName("type") val type: ReleaseTypeApi?,
    ...
)

However, the serializer behavior breaks down when null values come from the API:
{
    value: null,
    description: null
}

I marked the season and type fields as nullable in my ReleaseApi model. I also set isLenient, ignoreUnknownKeys and coerceInputValues flags. But it doesn't work.
How should I handle null values?
